# Getting gradient of vectorized function in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, derivative, autodiff

I am brand new to PyTorch and want to do what I assume is a very simple thing but am having a lot of difficulty.

I have the function `sin(x) * cos(x) + x^2` and I want to get the derivative of that function at any point.

If I do this with one point it works perfectly as

```
x = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.Tensor([4]),requires_grad=True)
y = torch.sin(x)*torch.cos(x)+torch.pow(x,2)
y.backward()
print(x.grad) # outputs tensor([7.8545])
```

However, I want to be able to pass in a vector as x and for it to evaluate the derivative element-wise. For example:

```
Input: [4., 4., 4.,]
Output: tensor([7.8545, 7.8545, 7.8545])
```

But I can't seem to get this working.

I tried simply doing

```
x = torch.tensor([4., 4., 4., 4.], requires_grad=True)
out = torch.sin(x)*torch.cos(x)+x.pow(2)
out.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

But I get the error "RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs"

How do I adjust this code for vectors?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/loss-backward-raises-error-grad-can-be-implicitly-created-only-for-scalar-outputs/12152) you can find relevant discussion about your error.

In essence, when you call `backward()` without arguments it is implicitly converted to `backward(torch.Tensor([1]))`, where `torch.Tensor([1])` is the output value with respect to which gradients are calculated.

If you pass `4` (or more) inputs, each needs a value with respect to which you calculate gradient. You can pass `torch.ones_like` explicitly to `backward` like this:

```
import torch

x = torch.tensor([4.0, 2.0, 1.5, 0.5], requires_grad=True)
out = torch.sin(x) * torch.cos(x) + x.pow(2)
# Pass tensor of ones, each for each item in x
out.backward(torch.ones_like(x))
print(x.grad)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks very much!