# Speed up derivatives in pytorch for vectorial functions

Tags: performance, pytorch, vectorization, derivative, autograd

I need to compute the first- and second-order derivatives of a vectorial function `output` in `batch x nvarout` (say 150) with respect to the input `x` in `batch x nvarin` (say 2).
I manage to do this with the following code:

```py
def continuous_diff(x, y):
    torch.set_grad_enabled(True)
    x.requires_grad_(True)
    # x in [N,nvarin]
    # y in [N,nvarout]
    # dy in [N,nvarin]
    dy_dx = torch.autograd.grad(
         y, x, torch.ones_like(y), 
        retain_graph=True, create_graph=True,)[0]
return dy_dx
```

and

```py
for k in range(output.shape[1]):
    y =  output[:,k]
    dx = continuous_diff(x,y)
    # hardcoded for nvarin = 2 here
    dxx = continuous_diff(x, dx[:,0])
    dyy = continuous_diff(x, dx[:,1])
    grad2 = torch.concatenate([dxx, dyy], dim=-1)
    output_grad2.append(grad2)
output_grad2 = torch.stack(output_grad2, dim=-1)
```

Is there a way to speed up this computation?

A similar question has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66120904/speeding-up-the-computation-of-second-order-derivatives-in-pytorch), but no solutions have been proposed since 2 years.